# How do I create a folder with a username and date as the folder name?

Tags: shell-script

I need to write a backup script. I need to be able to run the script from any computer and have it pull the username and date as the directory name. Each computer has an admin account and a user account. How can I pull the user account from a script and use it to name the backed up directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

folder name example: joe--2014-01-31

```
folder_name="${USER}--$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
mkdir "$folder_name"
```

Comment: wow. Your answer bears uncanny similarity to mine.

Comment: @tylerl That happens if the solution is obvious and several people write an answer simultaneously...

Comment: Note that `$USER` is not always set and not always to the value you'd wish. See also `$(logname)`, `$(id -run)` and `$(id -un)`  (and `$(whoami)`) depending on which user you actually mean.

Answer (score 2):

The current logged in user is typically stored in the `USER` environment variable. The current date is easily retrieved using the `date` command. So, just put them together.

```
echo "$USER--$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

Comment: Can I use the UID and get the same effect?

Comment: `UID` is distinct from the username, as it is a numerical designation.

Comment: If I know that each user will be a particular, in this case the same UID on a different machine, can I use it to find the name of the user and use that name in the script?